ERROR: Exception when publishing, exception message [Exec exit status not zero. Status [-1]]
I am facing an issue with Jenkins when I'm trying to connect Jenkins to mainframe via ssh publisher.
I don't know what the error is because it does not show any logs other than:
SSH: Connected
SSH: cd [/]
SSH: OK
SSH: Opening exec channel ...
SSH: EXEC: channel open
SSH: EXEC: STDOUT/STDERR from command [pwd; cd ../../../..; cd SYG1/ford/.p_batch_fcgcs/fcgcs/pitserver/bin/; ./stageclean.sh] ...
SSH: EXEC: connected
SSH: EXEC: completed after 987,902 ms
SSH: Disconnecting configuration [FACGFCNADev] ...
ERROR: Exception when publishing, exception message [Exec exit status not zero. Status [-1]]

In Jenkins pipeline I gave:
 transfers: [
                    sshTransfer(
                        execCommand: "pwd; cd ../../../..; cd $config.remoteRoot$config.remoteBin; ./stageclean.sh"
                    ),
                    sshTransfer(
                        execCommand: "pwd; cd ../../../../..; cd $config.remoteRoot$config.remoteDir; pwd; chmod 777 *.jar; ls -lart",
                        sourceFiles: "*",
                        remoteDirectory: config.remoteDir
                    )
                ]
            )
        ]


What's the timeout on the remote SSHD? Your first command takes 987902ms, or about sixteen and a half minutes, to complete.
